# How to identifi stripped functions in statically linked files

Tags: linux, disassembly, strip

I'm looking for a way to identify stripped functions in statically linked files.

Currently, I am considering a method of identification using a database.
As a result of examination, there is "IDA FLIRT", but it cannot be identified well. There may be a problem with the signature.
Ninjya Binary can also be identified, but I don't know how to do it.

Is there any other way to identify stripped functions?

---

Because I am not good at English, I use google translation. Therefore, I am sorry if English is wrong.

Comment: can you share the `bin` or file you want to investigate ?